# Capture delete event for PermissionSetAssignment

Tags: apex, profile, permission-sets

I am looking for ways to capture the `PermissionSetAssignment` record delete event and based on that I want to sync some details to the external system.

Things I tried

1. `Database.getDeleted` - Replication not supported error.
2. Tried to create a trigger on PermissionSetAssignment - trigger not supported error.
3. In apex, tried `[SELECT Id,SystemModstamp FROM PermissionSetAssignment ALL ROWS]` - recently deleted records not returned;
4. IsDeleted - field does not exist.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can view all this detail in audit trails. There is also object for audit trail on which you can query which is called SetupAuditTrail but you can only query on it nothing else

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_em_permission_sets.htm&type=5&release=232